# Get auto increment row ID when inserting with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting new data into a MySQL and I have a column called "bookingid" that is the primary key and has auto increment. I need to get the number of the auto increment after inserting my data, here is my code:

```
    try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   // prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations (bookingdatetime, firstname, lastname, address) 
VALUES (:bookingdatetime, :firstname, :lastname, :address)");

$stmt->bindParam(':bookingdatetime', $bookingdatetime);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $address);


// insert a row

$stmt->execute();

echo "success! row id: ";

}catch(PDOException $e){
echo json_encode(array("title" => "Database Error", "body" => $e->getMessage()));
}
$conn = null;
```

How do I echo the increment where it says "success! row id: "? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lastInsertId()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) to retrieve the last row that was inserted:

```
$stmt->execute();
echo "success! row id: $stmt->lastInsertId()";
```

Note that `lastInsertId()` **must** be called before `commit()` in a transaction, otherwise it will return `0`.

Comment: When I put "$bookingid = $stmt->lastInsertId();" it does't work...

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$lastInsertId in book.php on line 33

Comment: Needed to be $conn->lastInsertId()